# Sweet Alert Not Showing The Dynamic Value, What I Did Wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I ve set constructor like this:

```
...
constructor(props) 
        {
            super(props);
            this.state = 
            {          
                 progressBarValue: 0
            }

        }
...
```

The Call back function from NodeJS to ReactJS like This :

```
...
setTimeout(() => axios.post(BASE_URL + '/timer04')
   .then(res =>
      {  timerGrab = res.data;                                                            
         console.log(`Timer Value 04 :`+ timerGrab );                                                            
         var timerLocal = parseInt(timerGrab );                                                            
         this.setState({
              progressBarValue: timerLocal 
             })                                            
         console.log(`Data 04 NEW: `+ this.state.progressBarValue);
       })                    
   .catch(err =>                                               
      {                                                            
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
      }),10000)
...
```

On Sweet Alert 2 , I called the data that is transferred from NodeJS to ReactJS.

```
...

let timerInterval
    MySwal.fire(
    {         
        title: 'Processing...',
        html: this.state.progressBarValue+ `of 5 <br> <Progress animated value=${this.state.progressBarValue} max={5}/>`,
        timer: 62000,
...
```

The Output in the user interface, the progress bar does not work and look like this :

[image]

Also the output in the console look like this :

[image]

Any solutions guys?

Answer (score 1):

As you might have noticed having worked with some React - setState is asynchronous and as such you will be better off using the setState callback (you can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). So instead of this:

```
this.setState({
  progressBarValue: timerLocal 
})                                            
console.log(`Data 04 NEW: `+ this.state.progressBarValue);
```

You should try this:

```
this.setState({
  progressBarValue: timerLocal
}, () => console.log(`Data 04 NEW: ${this.state.progressBarValue}`));
```

Then it will report on the accurate value of this.state.progressBarValue

Comment: It does not update the value in the sweet alert tho